# How to fix "parse error on input" in haskell?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude Data.Set> :load hello
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( hello.hs, interpreted )

hello.hs:11:11: parse error on input `<-'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude Data.Set> h <- IO.openFile "testtext" IO.ReadMode
Prelude Data.Set>
```

The same line [h <- IO.openFile "testtext" IO.ReadMode] inside hello.hs throws the error. How do i fix this? What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT]
Source and output: http://pastebin.com/KvEvggQK

Comment: If Oswalds answer isn't helping you will probably need to show more code! Though, it seems it should solve your problem.

Comment: hi, what do i import to enable I/O?

Comment: i guess that line works inside Prelude because its also a part of the IO monad? Okay, i'll go read up first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only use `<-` inside a `do`-block¹ (which you're implicitly in in GHCI, but not in Haskell files).

In a Haskell file, you're only allowed to write bindings using `=`.

What you could do is put the following in the Haskell file:

```
myHandle = do h <- IO.openFile "testtext" IO.ReadMode
              return h
```

Though if you think about that for a bit, this is just the same as:

```
myHandle = IO.openFile "testtext" IO.ReadMode
```

However this way `myHandle` is still wrapped in `IO` and you'll need `<-` (or `>>=`) in ghci to unwrap it.

You can't write a Haskell file in such a way that just loading the file, will open `testtext` and give you the file handle.

---

¹ Or a list comprehension, but there the right operand of `<-` needs to be a list, so that has nothing to do with your situation.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
[h | h <- IO.openFile "testtext" IO.ReadMode]
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. You can't use `IO`s as the right operand to `<-` in a list comprehension.

Comment: My answer is at most partially wrong: [h <- IO.openFile "Copy Bin.txt" IO.ReadMode] produces a parse error, [h | h <- IO.openFile "Copy Bin.txt" IO.ReadMode] does not produce a parse error. Depending on the definition of IO.openFile it might not produce any error at all. Granted, it produces type error when the most common definition is used.